# Find command: how to ignore case?

Tags: find

I am looking for file "WSFY321.c" in a huge directory hierarchy.
Usually I would use [GNU find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/): `find . -name "WSFY321.c"`
But I do not know the case, it could be uppercase, lowercase, or a mix of both.

What is the easiest way to find this file?
Is there something better than `find . | grep -i "WSFY321.c"` ?

Answer (score 375, accepted):

Recent versions of GNU `find` have an `-iname` flag, for case-insensitive name searches.

```
find . -iname "WSFY321.c"
```

Comment: Also, since you're specifically looking for a file you can *probably* shave another couple of ticks off that with the `-type f` flag so it won't bother looking at the name if the inode is a directory. But that's pedantic levels of optimization...

Comment: For working with some regex you can do `find . -iname \*WSFY321.c\* -type f`

Comment: This pattern of adding `-i` before an option follows for other `find` options too. Ex: `-name` to search for a name, and `-iname` to make it case-insensitive. `-path` to search for a path, and `-ipath` to make it case-insensitive. I mention using `-ipath` in my answer here: [Stack Overflow: How to exclude a directory in find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69830768/4561887).

Answer (score 55):

With GNU find, or other versions of find that have it:

```
find . -iname 'WSFY321.c'
```

With other versions:

```
find . -name '[Ww][Ss][Ff][Yy]321.[Cc]'
```

Or a compromise that's slower but easier to type:

```
find . -name '????321.c' | grep -i '/WSFY[^/]*$'
```

Or in zsh:

```
print -rl -- **/(#i)WSFY321.c
```

Comment: *@Gilles* The `grep` version is filtering only upper case, and I don't understand the '[^/]' ..(not /)

Comment: @Gilles What is the argument to use the single quotes in the first case (exact filename) over no quotes at all?

Comment: @Peter.O No `*` after the `/` in the bash version. I meant `grep -i`. I use `[^/]*` rather than `.*` so as not to catch files in directories whose name begins with `WSFY`.

Comment: @Bernhard Consistency.

Comment: Thanks Gilles: I deleted the previous comment with incorrect syntax, and tested the ammended version, but it doesn't work without the \* (for an unexpected reason; to me at least).  The case-insensitive option no longer works: `shopt -s extglob nocaseglob globstar; printf '%s\n' **/WSFY321.c` ... I suppose that's why it is called a *nocase‍​* ***glob***: it only works in the context of a glob (or so it seems).

Comment: PS: Here is a way to use bash's *nocaseglob* without using the asterisk **\*** wildcard:  `shopt -s extglob nocaseglob globstar; printf '%s\n' **/[W]SFY321.c` ... The `[]` is *globby* enough...

Comment: @Peter.O Oh, I didn't expect this either. Bash is being weird. `**/WSFY321.[c]` does work. Zsh behaves in the same way if you use `setopt no_case_glob`, but using the case insensitive glob flag tells the shell that this is a glob anyway (and it's the same in ksh93 with `**/~(i:WSFY321.c)`).

Comment: PPS: The newer extended globing syntax in bash works without any quirky juggling involved: `shopt -s extglob nocaseglob globstar;  printf '%s\n' **/@(WSFY321.c)`

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions for macOS:

Using GNU `find`:

```
brew install findutils --with-default-names
# restart Terminal
find . -iname 'WSFY321.c'
```

Using GNU `sed`:

```
brew install gnu-sed --default-names
# restart Terminal
find -name "$(sed 's|\([[:alpha:]]\)|[\U\1\L\1]|g' <<<'WSFY321.c')"
```

Comment: On macOS Sierra the -iname option is available by default.